# WP_Nav_Walker extending, need to know count of Sub Menu Items

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, wp-nav-walker

I have 2 different displays here.  1 for mobile and another for desktop.  I need to output different html for both for just 1 menu item (the last 1) in a menu.  For example, given the following Menu structure:

```
- Menu Item 1
-- Child 1
-- Child 2
-- Child 3
- Menu Item 2
-- Child 1
-- Child 2
-- Child 3
-- Child 4
- Menu Item 3
-- Child 1
-- Child 2
-- Child 3
-- Child 4
-- Child 5
-- Child 6
```

I need to be able to output the following structure for Desktop:

```
<ul>
    <li>Menu Item 1
    <ul>
        <li>Child 1</li>
        <li>Child 2</li>
        <li>Child 3</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu Item 2
    <ul>
        <li>Child 1</li>
        <li>Child 2</li>
        <li>Child 3</li>
        <li>Child 4</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu Item 3
    <ul>
        <li>Child 1</li>
        <li>Child 2</li>
        <li>Child 3</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>&nbsp;
    <ul>
        <li>Child 4</li>
        <li>Child 5</li>
        <li>Child 6</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The last parent menu item with `$depth === 0` needs to be split in half into separate items.  But on mobile display, it does not need to be split in half, it should display perfect for mobile.

So I have 2 different `WP_Nav_Walker` extending classes.  1 for Mobile and another for Desktop which handle the menu differently, however the problem I'm facing is how to get the total count of Submenu items.  I understand how to know if a menu has children or not using `$args->has_children`, but how to get the total number of children??

I've created a variable to know which sub-menu item I'm on within the `end_el` function:

```
class Custom_Nav_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function __construct() {
        $this->boxitem_index = 0;
    }

    public function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
    {
        if ($depth === 0 && $this->menu_type == 'header')
        {
            echo '<pre>', var_dump($item), '</pre>';
        }
    }
}
```

I have also set a custom property called `menu_type` that gets set within the `start_el` function that attaches to the last menu here, so I'm able to know that it's the menu I want.

Basically, I need to split it in half, not by 3, but I'm not able to know what half is.  And ofcourse, I don't want to perform the if statement on the last item.  So, it would help to know how many items we have that are $depth === 1 for the last parent menu.  Is this possible?

The output I get for `$item` is this:

```
object(WP_Post)#723 (40) {
  ["ID"]=>
  int(73)
  ["post_author"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["post_date"]=>
  string(19) "2016-07-14 18:09:44"
  ["post_date_gmt"]=>
  string(19) "2016-07-14 18:09:44"
  ["post_content"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_title"]=>
  string(11) "Quick Links"
  ["post_excerpt"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_status"]=>
  string(7) "publish"
  ["comment_status"]=>
  string(6) "closed"
  ["ping_status"]=>
  string(6) "closed"
  ["post_password"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_name"]=>
  string(13) "quick-links-3"
  ["to_ping"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["pinged"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_modified"]=>
  string(19) "2016-07-21 17:12:08"
  ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
  string(19) "2016-07-21 17:12:08"
  ["post_content_filtered"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_parent"]=>
  int(0)
  ["guid"]=>
  string(30) "http://0b90b21a.ngrok.io/?p=73"
  ["menu_order"]=>
  int(12)
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(13) "nav_menu_item"
  ["post_mime_type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["comment_count"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["filter"]=>
  string(3) "raw"
  ["db_id"]=>
  int(73)
  ["menu_item_parent"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["object_id"]=>
  string(2) "73"
  ["object"]=>
  string(6) "custom"
  ["type"]=>
  string(6) "custom"
  ["type_label"]=>
  string(11) "Custom Link"
  ["title"]=>
  string(11) "Quick Links"
  ["url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["target"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["attr_title"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["description"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["classes"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(9) "menu-item"
    [2]=>
    string(21) "menu-item-type-custom"
    [3]=>
    string(23) "menu-item-object-custom"
    [4]=>
    string(22) "menu-item-has-children"
  }
  ["xfn"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["current"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["current_item_ancestor"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["current_item_parent"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Comment: _"The last parent menu item with $depth === 0 needs to be split in half into separate items"_ - why? Please explain what you are actually trying to _achieve_. There might be other options, that don't create a sub-optimal HTML structure, and use CSS to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: I am splitting into columns for desktop displays.  This is only way to support IE8 as site already does.  I am merging a site from ASP.NET (using Umbraco CMS) into PHP (using Wordpress) and need to maintain this HTML Structure for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Have you looked at what the $item data structure contains at that point?

Comment: Yes, I'm putting the code in the wrong function, but it doesn't matter, cause after I put it into the `start_lvl` function still nothing to be able to get the count of children... will edit code now.

Comment: Edited code, output gives me parent menu item as post object.

Comment: Apparently, I've been search everywhere for this, but don't think it's possible to get children count from a menu in wordpress within the `WP_Nav_Walker` class, which is odd, cause we are able to determine if it has children via `$args->has_children`.

Comment: I'd try something along the lines of counting how many items have the id of this item set as post_parent upfront. At a glance at the Walker_Nav_Menu class and its parent I have not spotted a suitable constructor or initialization method where to place this; so I would do it outside perhaps, and after getting the count add it as an additional property to the item element you have shown above, so that you can access it easily inside the walker when it comes upon this element.

Comment: I've already checked this, and the post id = 73, so I did a query in the database for any posts within the `wp_posts` table that have `post_parent = 73` and I got an empty result, so there must be a different way they are handling children menuitems.

Comment: How can it be that there is no way to get children menu items from a parent menu item, but there is a visual representation of this in the Wordpress Admin menu items section?  This seems very odd.  Why would they not include this in the Walker class by default?  This is probably 1 of the most important aspects to know when you are dealing with menus.

Comment: I guess implementing a function that hooks into [wp_get_nav_menu_object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_nav_menu_object/) and manipulates the menu object tree structure there would be the easiest way to go about this.

Comment: FYI:  I winded up taking a different path, I added a setting for each menu item to select the platform, "All Platforms", "Mobile", "Desktop".  And than just checked that setting in the mobile walker and desktop walker within `start_el` and `end_el` functions, and if it's not appropriate, set `$output = ""`  This means they will need to define another menu in here, but it provides way more flexibility now.  Thanks for your help just the same!  DONE and DONE!

Comment: I cooked up a little filter in the meantime, have a look at that, maybe still useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this filter function to get two additional properties `_children_count` and `_parent_children_count` on each item, that you can later evaluate in your menu walker:

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_objects_filter($sorted_menu_items) {
    foreach($sorted_menu_items as &$item) {
        $item->_children_count = 0;
        for($i=1, $l=count($sorted_menu_items); $i<=$l; ++$i) {
            if($sorted_menu_items[$i]->menu_item_parent == $item->ID) {
                $item->_children_count++;
            }
        }        
    }
    foreach($sorted_menu_items as &$item) {
        $item->_parent_children_count = 0;
        for($i=1, $l=count($sorted_menu_items); $i<=$l; ++$i) {
            if($item->menu_item_parent == $sorted_menu_items[$i]->ID) {
                $item->_parent_children_count = $sorted_menu_items[$i]->_children_count;
                break;                    
            }
        }
    }
    unset($item);
    return $sorted_menu_items;    
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_wp_nav_menu_objects_filter' );
```

---

Weirdly enough, it looks like the $sorted_menu_items array is numerically indexed *starting at 1*.
Added the `_` in front of the new properties as pseudo-namespacing, to avoid collisions with possible future official properties.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.

Comment: @CBroe sorry i`m a bit don't understand how i can use it in ``start_lvl``. in ``start_lvl`` we have only ``$args``.